# Is it possible to specify referrer in anchor element?

Tags: html, web, browser

Required behavor:

On page1.html is link which leads to page2.html, when link is visited, and back in history is initiated, instead of page1.html should be opened page3.html.

Comment: You can use the HTML5 history API for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Possible with javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

Comment: No you can't specify a referer, but you can change history.

Comment: Is it possible to make it with JavaScript but modifications should be only in page1.html?